# Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2 have 9

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

NSMutableDictionary *dictdata=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dictdata setObject:plant forKey:@"zoneName",@"LAS",@"searchPlant",@"SantaCruz",@"monthNo",@"10",@"year",@"2016"];

Comment: What your target result? It's unclear what you want.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is "plant"?

Comment: Did you copy something like `NSMutableDictionary *dictdata = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:object1, @"key1", object2, @"key2", object3, @"key3", nil]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictdata= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictdata setObject:@"LAS" forKey:@"zoneName"];
[dictdata setObject:@"SantaCruz" forKey:@"searchPlant"];
[dictdata setObject:@"10" forKey:@"monthNo"];
[dictdata setObject:@"2016" forKey:@"year"];
```

Key : Value set in dictionary like this

If you use any value:

```
NSString *yearString = [dictdata objectForKey:@"year"];
```